# Cam waves travelling at same direction interfere?

Tags: waves, superposition, speed

Can two waves travelling in same direction interfere?

Comment: How "same" is the same direction? Are two speakers beside each other emitting destructively interferring sounds same enough? Or do the speakers need to literally be occupying the same space?

Comment: Isn't that the case in a Michelson interferometer? The beams that bounce off each mirror eventually combine and go to the detector.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! It might be hard to have two separate wave sources that produce waves going in exactly the same direction (if you think about it geometrically, one source might block the other), so the two waves might only have to be going in the same direction *approximately* in most realistic experiments.

Here's a way to make two waves of light go in the exact same direction. Make a cavity, which is essentially a pair of mirrors that can support a standing wave of light in between them. One of the mirrors is made to be slightly transparent, so that we can input some light of a fixed wavelength into the cavity. Some of it passes through the first mirror, reflects off of the second mirror, then reflects off of the first mirror again, etc. Next, input some more light of the same wavelength into the cavity. If you time things right, the second beam of light can be going in the same direction as the first, so they can be made to interfere while going in the same direction (they will interfere regardless of the timing).

This whole experiment can probably be done with a string with partially fixed points. I'd imagine a guitar string fixed at two ends and almost fully fixed in the middle. Each side supports the same set of fixed wavelengths to make standing waves. If you lightly pluck one side, it will set a standing wave on that side with a small amplitude. Then, if you strongly pluck the other side, it will create a large-amplitude standing wave on the other side. If the middle point is slightly loose, some of the large-amplitude wave will leak onto the other side, so the two waves on that side will now interfere, even if they're traveling in the same direction.

Comment: If i kept a glass block and by using two identical light sources if i somehow send the lights through glass rod, via critical reflection by placing a horizontal gap between two normals will i able to get interference?

Comment: Only if the two waves overlap spatially. If they each travel through the glass parallel to each other (because of the horizontal gap) then I wouldn't expect any interference. You can think of limits: if the gap is extremely large, we should never expect any inerference. If the gap is very small, we will have to remember that light is not merely a ray travelling in a straight line, but really is exciting electrons in the glass that are then re-radiating light, so there will start to be more complicated interference effects as both beams try to excite atoms that are close to each other

Comment: If the two rays are close enough together, I would expect interference: the atoms in the glass will be affected by both beams of light, with the total effect being caused by the superposition of the two waves